# General Form for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am struggling to put a Series in a general form and was wondering if someone here could give a hand with that. If the question is to general or not meeting the standards, I apologize in advance.

Here it goes the example when `T=4`:

$a_4 = L_{0,4}(a_0 + s_1) + L_{1,3}s_2 + L_{2,2}s_{3} + W_{4}s_4$

What I need here is to find a general form, perhaps in summation form, for $a_{T}$.

Notice that:

1) The entries below every $L$ add up to $T$ but they are evolving in this fashion in which, from term to term in the summation, one has to take away $1$ from the right-hand side subscript and add up to the left-hand side subscript up to a point in which the last $L$ ($L_{2,2}$ in my example above) is in the form $L_{\frac{T}{2},\frac{T}{2}}$, For odd indexes, like $a_5$ I guess the only requirement is that the sum of the left-hand side subscript and the right one has to add up to $T$. (In this sense I guess that the left hand side subscript will be one unity bigger than the right-hand side one in the last term)

2) The last term is going to be invariably $W_Ts_T$

3) The term in parentheses in the first term always gonna be $(a_0 + s_1)$

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not stated what $L_{a,b}, s_a,w_a$ are.... Without any info, $ a_n$ could be anything.

Comment: Hi @user254665, $a$ and $s$ are $n \times 1$ vectors, whereas $L$ and $W$ are $n \times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting $a_4$ as follows may make it clearer:
$$\;\;\ L_{0,4}a_0\\
\color{red}{+L_{0,4}s_1\\
+L_{1,3}s_2\\
+L_{2,2}s_3}\\
+W_4 s_4$$
which can then be written as
$$\;\;\ L_{0,4}a_0\\
\color{red}{+\sum_{r=0}^2 L_{r,4-r}s_{r+1}}\\
+W_4 s_4$$

Substituting $4$ with $T$ and $2$ with $\big\lfloor \frac T2 \big\rfloor$ (the floor to cater for odd numbers) we have
$$a_T=L_{0,T}a_0+\color{red}{\left(\sum_{r=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac T2 \big\rfloor}L_{r,T-r}s_{r+1}\right)}+W_T s_T$$

This is the best guess from the information provided.

*(By the way, what do the variables represent?)*

Comment: Thank you, @hypergeometric. As I said above in the comments, $a$ and $s$ are $n \times 1$ vectors, whereas $L$ and $W$ are $n \times n$ matrices.